# sync timer with shorter timestamp than timer

Tags: c, synchronization, timestamp, overflow

Hy I have two devices A and B both are using a 64bit timer. One tick equals 1ns. I would like to syncronise the drift of both timer. I allready know the delay between A and B. Normally I would send the current time of A frequently to B. In B i would add the propagation delay and use this value as compare value to sync B. In my case I can only send the lower 32 bit of the timer every 100ms. I tried to simple replace the lower part of B with the part of A but this work only as long as there is no overflow of the 32 bit. Is there a way to detect this overflow? Overflow example (shorted timer):

timer B: 0x00FF

timer A: 0x010A

=> 0x0A to B 
replacing leads to 
timer B 0x000A instead of timer B 0x010A.

So I need to detect that in A a overflow already occured which hasn't occured in B.

Underflow example (shorted timer):

timer B: 0x0205

timer A: 0x01F6

=> 0xF6 => timer B: 0x02F6 instead of 0x01F6

In this case timer B is faster than timer A.

Comment: Why you can't simple compare if new value of 32bit is lower than previous?

Comment: @ Vladimir Tsykunov If the drift goes in the other direction a underflow would also be possible. I update question with a example

Comment: Overflow: If A faster than B than Avalue<Bvalue (lower 32 bit) otherwize Avalue>(Bvalue-threshold). Add a threshold to code of B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I'd use to find out the closest possible value of `timera`, given `timerb`, the 32 low bits of `timera` in `message`, and the expected propagation delay in `delay`:

```
#include <stdint.h>

int64_t expected_timera(const int64_t  timerb,
                        const uint32_t message,
                        const uint32_t delay)
{
    const int64_t  timer1 = (timerb / INT64_C(4294967296)) * INT64_C(4294967296)
                          + (int64_t)message + (int64_t)delay;
    const int64_t  timer0 = timer1 - INT64_C(4294967296);
    const int64_t  timer2 = timer1 + INT64_C(4294967296);

    const uint64_t delta0 = timerb - timer0;
    const uint64_t delta1 = (timer1 > timerb) ? timer1 - timerb : timerb - timer1;
    const uint64_t delta2 = timer2 - timerb;

    if (delta0 < delta1)
        return (delta0 < delta2) ? timer0 : timer2;
    else
        return (delta1 <= delta2) ? timer1 : timer2;
}
```

Personally, I would also calculate `timerb` from the actual timer B using a linear adjustment:

```
static volatile int64_t real_timer_b;  /* Actual timer b */
static int64_t          timerb_real;   /* real_timer_b at last sync time */
static int64_t          timerb_offset; /* timera at last sync time */
static int32_t          timerb_scale;  /* Q30 scale factor (0,2) */

static inline int64_t timerb(void)
{
    return ((int64_t)(int32_t)(real_timer_b - timerb_real) * (int64_t)timerb_scale) / INT64_C(1073741824) + timerb_offset;
}
```

With `timerb_real = 0`, `timerb_offset = 0`, and `timerb_scale = 1073741824`, `timerb() == real_timer_b`.

When `timera > timerb()`, you need to increase `timerb_scale`. When `timera < timerb()`, you need to decrease `timerb_scale`. You do not want to calculate the exact value every 100ms, because then jitter in propagation delay would directly affect `timerb()`; you want to adjust it slowly, over several (dozens) of seconds. As a bonus, you can keep `timerb()` monotonic, without sudden jumps forward or backwards.

[Network Time Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) implementations do something very similar, and you might find further implementation help there.